Event loop is closed Python Async
I've built an email script , utilising a user's app key from google to get access to their email. However when i run the script i get the error 'Runtime Error: event loop is closed.
On initial discovery I decided to rebuild the function as I was the one who built it so maybe I just did something wrong:
async def main():
    industry = 'resturaunts'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        next_page_token = None
        companies = await process_industry(industry, session, next_page_token)
        for company in companies:
            await outreach_to_company(session, company,10)

Above is my attempt on making it operate on single item of industry. Which in turn returned the runtime error. I then tried another solution where I used a single function send_email:
 async def main():
     await send_email("tgjadore@gmail.com", 'Company')

Which actually worked however this isn't the full functionality of the script. I then tried:
async def main():
    industries = ['restaurants', 'barbers', 'cafes', 'gyms']

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for industry in industries:
            next_page_token = None
            while True:
                companies = get_companies(industry, next_page_token)
                if not companies or 'places' not in companies:
                    print('Nothing to scrape')
                    break

                tasks = [outreach_to_company(session, company) for company in companies['places']]
                print(tasks)
                await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

                if 'nextPageToken' not in companies:
                    print('No nextPageToken')
                    break

                next_page_token = companies['nextPageToken']
                await asyncio.sleep(10)

Which crashes after all print statement of nothing to scrape.
Here is the full script in case it helps with anything (mail.py): https://github.com/JadoreThompson/Email-Outreach-Bot/tree/development

What problem are you trying to solve?  Would you prefer that the program exit gracefully rather than printing out the RuntimeError, or is the problem that it's actually supposed to scrape something?

The problem is that the program is supposed to scrape however, when it's called to run, it runs a runtime error

To fix this, I'm not sure if this is common throughout all applications but it worked for me. Setting an event loop policy which'll create a new event loop and set the current one:
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

